# Swift Guard Critical Sections of Concurrent Code (similar to mutex lock in c?)

Tags: swift, swift-concurrency

```
func resetLobby() async {
    do {
        lobbyViewModel.pauseListener()
        let question = lobbyViewModel.currentLobby?.questionDeck?.currentQuestion
        if let winner, let question {
            print("Reset Lobby: ")
            try await lobbyViewModel.resetLobby(winner: winner, question: question)
        }
        try await lobbyViewModel.nextQuestion()
        lobbyViewModel.restartListener()
        // try await lobbyViewModel.nextQuestion()
        if let id = userViewModel.currentUser?.id, let num = lobbyViewModel.currentLobby?.number {
            try await userViewModel.loadUser(userId: id, lobbyNumber: num)
        }
    } catch {
        award = true
    }
}
```

I have an application with multiple users per lobby, with listeners attached to every user to update based on the lobby. Currently, the users fire while resetLobby is running, resulting in a race condition and incorrect attributes being returned to the users. Is there a Swift/async-friendly way to ensure that resetLobby() is treated as a block of code, and the listeners don't fire until resetLobby() is finished?

Note: The pause/start listeners work for the local listener, but not for the lobby-wide listeners.

Comment: Only call `resetLobby` from an async stream, (eg `for await ... { resetLobby() }`)`

Comment: Put the code into an Actor.

Comment: @matt Actors don't prevent reentrancy. This code has multiple suspension points and `resetLobby` could get called again during those suspensions.

Comment: @jnpdx They prevent race conditions, and they can be configured to prevent reentrancy, i.e. an actor that buffers and serializes (and the Apple async stream algorithms have stuff that helps serialize calls as well).

Comment: This is the sort of thing for which asynchronous sequences are very well suited. It lets you process these events sequentially (even when the handler has `await` calls). A simple [`AsyncStream`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/asyncstream) sometimes is sufficient. Or an [`AsyncChannel`](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms/blob/main/Sources/AsyncAlgorithms/AsyncAlgorithms.docc/Guides/Channel.md) handles posting of new events, too. We'd need to see the listener code to advise further.